# Is There More Pythonic Way to Extract Scattered Values?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a very basic thing, I want to charge values according to a priority,  so that if a variable alone isn't sufficient, another variable can be used in conjunction. I rewrote the function few times and the best I came up with is below, yet I still feel like it is unnecessarily convoluted for something so simple and bound to become inefficient after I expand it.

```
class Wallet:
    Upper, Lower = 5, 5
    @classmethod
    def Pay(self,Cost):
        Total = sum([self.Upper+self.Lower])
        if Total >= Cost:
            Total = Total-Cost
            self.Upper = max(0,Total-self.Lower)
            self.Lower = max(0,Total-self.Upper)
            print('Upper pocket: %s\nLower pocket: %s' % (self.Upper,self.Lower))
        else: print('Purchase failed; the product is too expensive.')
Wallet.Pay(7)
```

Comment: Your accumulator, `Total` would best be renamed to `total` It is best practice to have variables names start with a lowercase letter An example of something which does get to have uppercase first letter is a class name.

Comment: Did you mean for `Upper` and `Lower` to be static class variables? If instead you want each instance/object to have its own `Upper` and `Lower` member variables then it would make sense to assign them to the object in `def __init__(self):` (`__init__` is sort of like a constructor, but not exactly)

Comment: @Toothpick Anemone I knew about that style preference and still neglected to implement it, but now that you mentioned, its usage would make things clearer.

Comment: @Toothpick Anemone Yes, I wanted to make them class variables. I know how `init` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Firstly,

you do not need `sum([self.Upper+self.Lower])`. Either of the following would be sufficient:

```
# comma instead of plus-sign
sum([self.Upper, self.Lower]) 

# only plus-sign
# do not make a list and pass it to the `sum()` function
self.Upper + self.Lower
```

## Secondly,

it would actually ***increase*** the number of lines of code you have, but greatly improve readability, if you were to distinguish between old, stale, values and new, fresh, values, like this:

```
class Wallet:
    upper, lower = 5, 5
    @classmethod
    def Pay(cls, price):
        old_upper = cls.upper
        old_lower = cls.lower
        old_funds = cls.upper + cls.lower
        if old_funds >= price:
            new_funds = old_funds - price
            new_upper = max(0, new_funds - old_lower)
            new_lower = max(0, new_upper - new_upper)
            cls.upper = new_upper
            cls.lower = new_lower
            print('upper pocket: %s\nlower pocket: %s' % (cls.upper, cls.lower))
        else:
            print('Purchase failed; the product is too expensive.')
```

## Thirdly,

You can reduce how "unnecessarily convoluted" your code seems (as you described it), by adding some comments:

```
class Wallet:
    upper, lower = 5, 5
    @classmethod
    def Pay(cls, price):
        old_upper = cls.upper
        old_lower = cls.lower
        old_funds = cls.upper + cls.lower
        if old_funds >= price:
            new_funds = old_funds - price
            # funds in the upper pocket are consumed before any
            # funds in the lower pocket.
            #
            # If we did not have to use funds from the lower-pocket, then
            # what remains in the upper-pocket is all of our remaining money
            # less whatever was, and still is, in the lower pocket.
            #
            # set new_upper to zero if we used it all
            new_upper = max(0, new_funds - old_lower)

            # Whatever money is not in the upper pocket is now in the lower-pocket
            new_lower = max(0, new_funds - new_upper)
            cls.upper = new_upper
            cls.lower = new_lower
            print('upper pocket: %s\nlower pocket: %s' % (cls.upper, cls.lower))
        else: # not enough money to pay for the item
            print('Purchase failed; the product is too expensive.')
```

## Fourthly,

setting the funds in lower pocket to zero, if (`new_funds - old_lower`), is negative is a bad idea. The only way `new_funds - old_lower` is negative is if you do not have enough money in the wallet to pay the given price.

Given that `new_lower = max(0, new_funds - new_upper)` is executed only-if you do have enough money to buy the item, then setting `cls.lower` masks/hides the error which that `new_funds - new_upper` is not supposed be negative!

## Fifth,

The only indication anyone receives that there is not enough money to pay for the item, is the message `Purchase failed; the product is too expensive.` on `stdout`. I could make invalid calls to `Wallet.Pay()` all day long, and the software would have no idea that there was not enough money to pay for the item, because the software is probably not reading `stdout`

Instead, you could return a status-flag:

```
class Wallet:    
    @classmethod
    def Pay(cls, price):
        if available_funds >= price:
            flg = 0 # clear flag. no error code       
        else: # not enough money to pay for the item
            flg = 1 # error code 1. Not enough funds to pay for the item
        return flg
```

... or throw an exception:

```
class Wallet:    
    @classmethod
    def Pay(cls, price):
        if available_funds >= price:
            # do your stuff     
        else: # not enough money to pay for the item
            raise ValueError('Purchase failed; the product is too expensive.')
```

## In the end, I would do something like this:#

```
class Wallet:
    pockets = [5, 5]

    @classmethod
    def priceSpecToPocketSpec(cls, price):
        """
                Translates a specification for
                how much to pay in terms of a price, into
                a specification for how much to pay
                in terms of which pockets to empty completly
                an how much money to leave in the last pocket.

                e.g. " Empty Pockets 0, 1, and 2.
                       Empty pocket 3, except for 3.60 USD"

                :param price:
                :return:
        """
        # Implemention is a little like a ripple-carry adder:
        unpaid_balance = price
        for idx in range(0, len(cls.pockets)):
        # for each pocket
            # reduce the unpaid balance by the amount in the current pocket
            unpaid_balance -= cls.pockets[idx]
            if unpaid_balance <= 0: # if unpaid_balance is paid for
                # record how much the balance was overpaid by ("change")
                change = (-1) * unpaid_balance
                # idx == index of pocket to insert change into
                return idx, change
        # at this point, emptying out all pockets
        # would not be enough to pay for the unpaid_balance
        return None, None

    @classmethod
    def emptyUpperPockets(cls, sentinel):
        for idx in range(0, sentinel):
            cls.pockets[idx] = 0

    @classmethod
    def payByPocketSpec(cls, idx, change):
        """
        Instead of accepting a specification for
        how much to pay in terms of a price, this function
        accepts a specification for how much to pay
        in terms of index of pocket
        to put change into and the amount of change to
        enter.

        In order to pay with only some of what is in
        the last pocket, we first pay with the entire
        contents of the pocket, then receive change.

        All pockets with indices 0, 1, 2,..., idx - 1
        are emptied

        :param idx:  index of pocket to insert change into
        :param change:
        :return:
        """
        # empty out upper pockets and
        # put change into the specified pocket
        cls.emptyUpperPockets(idx)
        cls.pockets[idx] = change
        return

    @classmethod
    def pay(cls, price):
        pocket_idx, change = cls.priceSpecToPocketSpec(price)
        if isinstance(pocket_idx, type(None)):
            raise ValueError('Purchase failed; the product is too expensive.')
        cls.payByPocketSpec(pocket_idx, change)
        print('upper pocket: %f\nlower pocket: %f' % (cls.pockets[0], cls.pockets[1]))

def print_pay_and_reset(price):
    divider = '-' * 40
    print(divider)
    try:
        print('attempt to buy something of price:', price)
        Wallet.pay(price)
        print('purchase succeeded')
    except Exception as exc:
        sexc = str(exc)
        print(sexc)
    print(divider)
    Wallet.pockets = [5, 5]

for price in [0, 2, 7, 99999999999]:
    print_pay_and_reset(price)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such an informative answer; this will go a long way, and sorry for the late approval (I didn't notice your answer).